# TypeError : 'NoneType' object is not callable (XLNet Classifer)

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, text-classification

I am trying to train my model using Tokenizer,Keras and TensorFlow.
Code where I'm getting the error.

```
from transformers import TFXLNetModel, XLNetTokenizer
xlnet_model = 'xlnet-large-cased'
xlnet_tokenizer = XLNetTokenizer.from_pretrained(xlnet_model)
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: Please do **not** post screenshots of code or error messages - see how to create a [MRE].

Answer (score 3):

If you run the code you will first get this error:

```
ImportError: 
XLNetTokenizer requires the SentencePiece library but it was not found in your environment. Checkout the instructions on the
installation page of its repo: https://github.com/google/sentencepiece#installation and follow the ones
that match your environment
```

After running `!pip install sentencepiece` and restarting the cell the `TypeError` happens.

To fix this you need to restart your runtime. Click "Runtime -> Restart Runtime", then run your cells again.

I found this solution on the `transformers` repo in [this issue report](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/10797#issuecomment-802802019).